# Flutter: Apple declines my app because having "push notification without using the APN API"

Tags: ios, flutter, apple-push-notifications

I have made a small App using flutter for our volleyball team but Apple declines publishing the App because we're having "push notification without using the APN API."

Full mail:

> Guideline 4.5.4 - Design - Apple Sites and Services
>
> Your app does not request and obtain the user's consent before sending
> push notifications, which is not appropriate for the App Store.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please revise your app to obtain the user's
> consent prior to delivering notifications in the app.
>
> Resources
>
> For information on working with push notifications, please review User
> Notifications framework and Technical Note TN2265 Troubleshooting Push
> Notifications.
>
> Please see attached screenshots for details.

Since my App asks for the user Consent on installation, I did not understand the complaint and asked for further advice.

The Answer:

> Hello,
>
> Thank you for your reply.
>
> Regarding 4.5.4, we noticed that your app provides push notification
> without using the APN API.
>
> To resolve this issue, it would be appropriate to use the APN API.
>
> Resources
>
> For additional information and instructions on requesting permission,
> please review the Requesting Permission section of the iOS Human
> Interface Guidelines and the Information Property List Key Reference.
> You may also want to review the Technical Q&A QA1937: Resolving the
> Privacy-Sensitive Data App Rejection page for details on how to
> provide a usage description for permission request alerts.
>
> We look forward to reviewing your resubmitted app.
>
> Best regards,

I am really unhappy with the answer "it would be appropriate to use the APN API", because to my (not native language) english understanding it means, I do not need to implement the notifications via APN API, but it would be nice.

Furthermore I have checked all the attached documentation, but found no clue giving me a hint what I am doing wrong.

The reason why I do not use the APN API is that I am using [Local Notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) as flutter package for the push notifications and there is not APN configuration.

Can anybody help me getting the app to the AppStore? What do I need to do to get it approved?

Comment: Have you read this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/asking_permission_to_use_notifications

Comment: So all they want is a simple "Permission Request"? Nothing with the APN API?

Comment: How did you asked for the notification permission, with a custom alert dialog?

Comment: yes a custom widget on installation

Comment: You need to do it with a plugin or native way. I updated my answer. In your method you only alert the user but OS doesn't know anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/asking_permission_to_use_notifications) you need to ask permissions to user.

> Local and remote notifications get the user’s attention by displaying
>   an alert, badging your app’s icon, or playing sounds. These
>   interactions occur when your app isn’t running or is in the
>   background. They let users know that your app has relevant information
>   for them to view. Because the user might consider notification-based
>   interactions disruptive, you must obtain permission to use them.

[permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) plugin might help you with this.

```
enum PermissionGroup {
  ...

  /// Android: Check notification enable
  /// iOS: Check and request notification permission
  notification

  ...
}
```